# How to identify identical SSD in Windows 11

Tags: windows, ssd, serial-number

I have two identical M.2 SSDs in my PC and I'm trying to find out in Windows 11 which disk is which. I've ran wmic to find the serial number, but it's not the same as on the sticker. The SN on the sticker is 5 digits, followed by a letter and another 6 digits. The serial number Windows reports is 8 groups of 4 hex characters. Is there anyway to compare these? I've already tried some basic hex conversions, but without luck.

Note: I'm still in the Windows 11 setup, so I'm looking for a CMD/PowerShell solution.

Comment: Is there any chance of powering off the computer and removing one of the drives?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, that's what I've ended up doing now, it sucks though.

Comment: When one of the disks is removed, you can see its serial number and know which one is what.

Comment: @harrymc I think the OP was saying that the serial number reported by wmic had no correspondence to the serial number on the label.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Yes, but he can create that correspondence when only one disk is in the computer.